# VSCode API: How to register callback/provider for keyboard cursor position change?

Tags: vscode-extensions

Is there a way to register a callback function/provider in a Visual Studio Code extension that would trigger on every keyboard cursor position change?

Comment: Please define what is "every keyboard cursor movement". Did you try `onDidChangeTextDocument: Event<TextDocumentChangeEvent>` https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace ?

Comment: See `vscode.window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection()` - it will fire on every cursor position change, which can be annoying if you just move the cursor by an arrow key.

Comment: I updated the question. What I need is a callback that would trigger on every update of the cursor position in the document (which could happen when you press keyboard arrow buttons or select a new cursor position with the mouse).  `onDidChangeTextDocument` as I understand would only trigger when the document content is updated. I will try `vscode.window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection()`, thanks so much!

Comment: For a possible "debouncing" solution to all the events when changing a selection, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49050990/836330.